# Java Reflection with Object... as a parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I'm wanting to use Java reflection to call a method on a class of mine that has the following signature:

```
public Object execute(Object...params)
```

In my loader class, I have the class loaded, but I'm not sure how to setup my getMethod call. Currently, I have something like this:

```
Method classEntry = _loadedClass.getMethod("execute", new Class[]{Object[].class});
```

I then try to invoke this method after creating a newInstance of my class by calling:

```
Object classObj = _loadedClass.newInstance();
classEntry.invoke(classObj, params); // params comes in from the method as Object...params
```

This is giving me a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` Exception. I know that my issue lies in my getMethod call. How should I set that up to accept a params object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `params` is of type `Object []` then you need to call `invoke` like this:

```
classEntry.invoke(classObj, new Object [] {params});
```

But this does not explain `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: That fixed it! Adding that in fixed everything. I love quick fixes! Thanks again!